# При импорте данных Excel в Visual Studio обрезаются лидирующие нули

Tags: c#, excel

Пытаюсь в DataTable вставить некоторые поля excel файла, но при импорте обрезаются лидирующие нули в колонках. (Они нужны.) Может, кто решал такую проблему.

Делаю именно так. С помощью ConnectionString не могу выбирать, ибо файл содержит не только данные, но и еще разную информацию типа заголовков, шапок таблиц и названий подразделов прямо среди табличных данных. Соответственно, способ с использованием schema.ini не поможет. Ещё и потому, что в таблицах постоянно разное количество полей (те, что нужны, всегда на месте). Если кто-то знает, как решить проблему с нулями, отпишитесь.

P.S. Возможности поставить в исходном excel файле тип у всех интересующих полей "Текст" нету.

```
    private static DataTable[] parseSeti (string[] seti)
    {
        // Создаем экземпляр приложения Excel
        Excel.Application excelApl=new Excel.Application();
        // Скрываем вывод окна приложения
        excelApl.Visible = false;   

        DataTable[] sTable = new DataTable[seti.Count()];
        int sTableIndex = 0;

        foreach (string set in seti)
        {
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApl.Workbooks.Open(@set, 
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Excel.Sheets excelWorkSheets=excelWorkBook.Worksheets;
            //Получаем ссылку на лист 1
            Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet=(Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkSheets.get_Item(1);                

            // Создаем новый экземпляр таблицы в массиве sTable
            sTable[sTableIndex] = new DataTable();

            // Создаем колонки у таблицы
            foreach (string colH in hName)
            {
                sTable[sTableIndex].Columns.Add(colH);
            }

            // Выбираем тот диапазон ячеек который используется
            Excel.Range exRange = excelWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            // Цикл перебирает строки в диапазоне с данными
            // Начинаем с девятой строки. От туда начинаются данные.
            for (int r = 9; r <= exRange.Rows.Count; r++)
            {
                // Проверяем чтоб первая ячейка не содержала название подраздела
                if(String.Compare(Convert.ToString((exRange.Cells[r,2] as Excel.Range).Value2),"") == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Если не вылетели на предыдущем этапе, то это строка с данными
                // Создаем пустую строку в sTable...
                DataRow dRow = sTable[sTableIndex].NewRow();

                // ... заполняем содержимым...
                string tmp = Convert.ToString((exRange.Cells[r, 2] as Excel.Range).Value2);
                dRow[0] = tmp;
                tmp = Convert.ToString((exRange.Cells[r, 8] as Excel.Range).Value2);
                dRow[1] = tmp;
                tmp = Convert.ToString((exRange.Cells[r, 11] as Excel.Range).Value2);
                dRow[2] = tmp;
                tmp = Convert.ToString((exRange.Cells[r, 9] as Excel.Range).Value2);
                dRow[3] = tmp;

                // ... и добавляем её в конец таблицы
                sTable[sTableIndex].Rows.Add(dRow);
            }

            // переходим к следующей таблице.
            sTableIndex++;
        }

        excelApl.Quit();
        return sTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо Value2 использовать FormulaLocal (если в получаемых данных нет формул) или Text (может обрезать).

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что уже когда создан объект Excel.Application, там уже нули порезаны, а не в момент чтения конкретной ячейки. То есть он конвертит строку в число на этапе выполнения кода 
Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook=excelApl.Workbooks.Open(@set,Type.Missing...
Может, есть возможность заставить его при открытии (или создании объекта) принудительно задать, что считать все ячейки текстовыми.

Comment: Так если книгу просто открыть в  Excel - нули будут? Какой формат ячеек?

Comment: Если книгу открыть в Excel, нули есть. Формат Ячеек - Дополнительный: АФМ, язык греческий. Если поставить тип текстовый, то ноль тут же съедается.

Comment: Форматом поля задано, что должны быть нули. Значит, вариантов у Вас два: 1) все-таки использовать свойство Text: 2) если маска не сложная (просто N нулей) - читать NumberFormat и "добивать" Value2 до нужной длины. Маску можете посмотреть в свойствах ячейки, форматы, все форматы.

Comment: Ни то, ни то не сработало. Ладно. Прорвемся. Спасибо за желание помочь.

Comment: Киньте куда-нибудь на файлообмен кусок этого excel (пару строк буквально). На обычных форматах, типа почтового индекса (тоже лид-нули добавляются), отработало прекрасно.